# Hide text from one magento store

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I have two stores created, retail and wholesale. I created a static block visible in both the stores. Without logging in, i want to hide a line when somebody opens the wholesale page using css display:none.

I need to a php code that would detect different stores so i can add css class. I've seen examples for logged in users but not for stores.

Example code that i'm looking for:

```
<?php
if (store = wholesale) then
else if…
end if
?>
```

Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
$storeCode = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode();
if($storeCode == 'default')
{
          /* your code here */
};
```

Comment: I added this but its not working! What could be the reason?
    $storeCode = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode();
    if($storeCode == 'wholesale')
    {
    echo 'hello world';
    };

Comment: make sure your store code registered on backend on menu system->manage store, look at store view name code & it's configured correctly...or debug use echo $storeCode;

Answer (score 0):

You can apply store condition as per below :

```
 if (Mage::app()->getStore()->getId() == YOUR STORE VIEW ID HERE)
 {
   //apply your custom code here
 }
 or
if (Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode() == YOUR STORE VIEW CODE HERE)
 {
   //apply your custom code here
 }
```

Apply your store id or code and put them in condition accordingly.